# F# record and evaluating of this

Tags: syntax, f#

I'm struggling a bit with a F#-assignment, which I hope you can answer for mere: I have that

> We will use the type `OrderedList<’a>` declared as follows

```
type OrderedList<’a when ’a : equality> = 
    { front: ’a list
    ; rear: ’a list}
```

> For instance, the value `let ex = {front = [’x’]; rear = [’z’;’y’]}` has
>   type `OrderedList<char>` and represents the ordered list `[’x’, ’y’, ’z’]`.

The question that I'm struggling with is:

> We define the canonical representation of an ordered list to be the
>   representation where the rear list is empty.  Declare a function
>   `canonical:OrderedList<’a>->OrderedList<’a>`, where `canonical ol` returns
>   the canonical representation of `ol`.

Just as a startup, I've tried something:

```
let canonicial (list:OrderedList<'a>)= 
    match list with
    | {x::xs}, {y::xss} -> if x = y then "SUCCESS!!!!" else failwith "FEJL!!!"
    | _ -> failwith "Some"
```

My issue is that I don't know how to get to the element in the type / the syntax for this. I know the function has not been solved correctly, but right now I focus mostly on the syntax.

Hope to get some help!

Comment: Have you read the msdn documentation on pattern matching?

Comment: Yes, and I cannot seem to figure it out. :(

Comment: reread the section entitiled 'record pattern'

Comment: to be honest I would recommend adding complete signature like `let cononical (ol : OrderedList<'a>) : OrderedList<'a>` this will help you find some basic issues you already have

Comment: because right now you have a signature `canonical : OrderedList<'a> -> string` ;)

Comment: then please try to think about what you have to do - remember canonical means that the `rear` is empty - so you have to cases: when it already is and when it is not - the first should be easy and the second you have to think a bit of how to move things from the rear to the front (*hint*: you might want to do something with the order of elements)

Comment: As written in my question, I mostly focused on the syntax of this, but of course it'll help if I change it. I will to see if I can get any further :)

Comment: btw: what course are you taking that is using F#? (happy to see such :D)

Comment: I study Software Development, and we have a course in Functional Programming using F# :p. I failed the exam last time, so that's why I use extra time time to practise :)

Comment: I cannot seem to get the elements of the list in the record. I try something like let canonicial (list:OrderedList<'a>) : OrderedList<'a> = 
    match list with
    | {[]}. Help? :o

Comment: ouch - good luck :D - btw: your syntax is a bit of - you really need something like `match list.rear with ...` - see you are only interested in the `rear` (remember a list) - now just do the obvious (empty/non-empty case) - the syntax for pattern-matching inside the record would be `match list with | { front = _; rear = ... }`

Comment: maybe the naming is a problem - it's no F# list - it's a record of your `OrderedList` type - this is why I would have named it `ol` (like your Prof. did)

Answer (score 2):

Well I think I can give you the solution now (you surely have more problems to solve):

```
let canonical = 
   function   
   | { front = _; rear = [] } as ol -> ol
   | { front = fs; rear = rs } -> { front = fs @ List.rev rs; rear = [] }
```

as you can see the first case is when the rear is already empty - here it's enough to give to original back

in the other case we have to get a new `OrderedList<'a>` with the reversed old rear appended to the old front - that's it - you don't even need the constraint on `'a` - and indeed I find it strange to put it there - usually it's better to but the constraints on the functions in FP - but well different styles and stuff.

I hope this helps you out a bit

BTW: I used `function` on purpose - you should try to convert this into your usual `match ... with ...` style so you can get your syntax right

Comment: hey - FP is *the* future - chances are good that you *will* have to write functional code - be it Java, Swift, Haskell, F#, JavaScript, whatever - you gonna code - you gonna better be functional (it's *really* looking a bit this way right now - so better don't forget - learn to master not to pass!)

Comment: I shall remember, sir! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, thanks, thanks! Now I better understand this topic! I rewritten your code to:

```
let canonical2 (ol:OrderedList<'a>) : OrderedList<'a> = 
    match ol with
    |{ front = _; rear = []} -> ol
    |{ front = f; rear = r} -> {front = f @ List.rev r; rear = []}
```

Comment: yes that looks good ;) - but remember in this case you can just do `match ol.rear with ...` as well and you will get away with far less key-strokes and `{}` :D

Comment: also FPlers like to write `rs` and `xs` and stuff to say that those are a list (or a other collection) of values ;) - so guess what `xss` are?

Comment: exactly - see - those appendes s`s are useful after all

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it granted that @ already takes care of returning the "other list" if one is empty (so shouldn't be an overhead to always append) :

```
let canonical ol = { ol with front = ol.front @ List.rev ol.rear; rear = [] }
// or
let canonical { front = fs; rear = rs } = { front = fs @ List.rev rs; rear = [] }
```

Comment: of course this one is **wrong** as you append the rear in the reverse order - but yeah the idea itself is not bad ;)